# swift 2.3 how to properly use deprecated CBCentralManagerState

Tags: ios10, xcode8, swift2

I'm just converting my project to swift 2.3 (XCode 8 beta 6) and I can't figure out how to use enum CBManagerState on old iOS versions (my app has deployment target iOS7).

CBCentralManager state now uses different enum CBManagerState (it was CBCentralManagerState before).

Code below does not compile because manager.state can't be compared with deprecated enum CBCentralManagerState so what should I put into else block?

Thanks for any advise!

```
func isBluetoothAvailable() -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        return manager.state == CBManagerState.PoweredOn
    } else {
        return manager.state == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is a solid solution but removing the enum type seems to work...

```
func isBluetoothAvailable() -> Bool {
    return manager.state == .PoweredOn
}
```